# How to disable go_collector metrics in prometheus/client_golang

Tags: go, monitoring, prometheus

I am using a NewGaugeVec to report my metrics:

```
elapsed := prometheus.NewGaugeVec(prometheus.GaugeOpts{
    Name: "gogrinder_elapsed_ms",
    Help: "Current time elapsed of gogrinder teststep",
}, []string{"teststep", "user", "iteration", "timestamp"})
prometheus.MustRegister(elapsed)
```

All works fine but I noticed that my custom exporter contains all metrics from prometheus/go_collector.go:

```
# HELP go_gc_duration_seconds A summary of the GC invocation durations.
# TYPE go_gc_duration_seconds summary
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0"} 0.00041795300000000004
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.25"} 0.00041795300000000004
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.5"} 0.00041795300000000004
...
```

I suspect that this is kind of a default behavior but I did not find anything in the documentation on how to disable that. Any ideas on how to configure my custom exporter so that these default metrics disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible in the Go client, once https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/issues/46 is complete you'll have a way to do this.

In general you want your custom exporter to export these, the only ones I'm aware of where it doesn't currently make sense are the snmp and blackbox exporter.

Incidentally `timestamp` seems odd as a label, if you want that you should likely be using logging rather than metrics. See https://blog.raintank.io/logs-and-metrics-and-graphs-oh-my/
The Prometheus way would be to have the timestamp as a value, not as a label.

Comment: hmm, if I remember correctly prometheus claims not to be opinionated... If say I maintain a network of humidity sensors for my potted plants. I think it is odd if a plant reports its number of goroutines, gc statistics and such. Good to know that this is already been worked on. Thanks for the metrics article!

Comment: Prometheus is quite opinionated, as a lot of things that seem like a good idea at first glance are actually anti-patterns. It's important to have all the key systems metrics, and that includes how the exporter itself is performing. Getting that automatically with the scrape is almost always the right thing to do. Something for potted plants may fall into the category where it doesn't make sense and you should monitor the exporter separately, depending on the exact architecture.

Comment: It looks like that issue is complete but there's still no way to disable this. There's `init()` (Golang calls this) down there that uncondititionally starts the Go runtime and Process collectors: https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/blob/69bb3870645f63c67a8dc9c9ef94585fd0d98c80/prometheus/registry.go#L51

Answer (score 16):

Well the topic is rather old but in case others have to deal with it.
The following code works fine with current codebase [v0.9.0-pre1](https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/tree/v0.9.0-pre1)

```
// [...] imports, metric initialization ...

func main() {
  // go get rid of any additional metrics 
  // we have to expose our metrics with a custom registry
  r := prometheus.NewRegistry()
  r.MustRegister(myMetrics)
  handler := promhttp.HandlerFor(r, promhttp.HandlerOpts{})

  // [...] update metrics within a goroutine

  http.Handle("/metrics", handler)
  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":12345", nil))
}
```

Comment: Just verified that is also works with version [1.0.0](https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/releases/tag/v1.0.0) of the codebase.

Answer (score 4):

I would simply do it this way ->

```
// Register your collectors
elapsed := prometheus.NewGaugeVec(prometheus.GaugeOpts{
    Name: "gogrinder_elapsed_ms",
    Help: "Current time elapsed of gogrinder teststep",
}, []string{"teststep", "user", "iteration", "timestamp"})
prometheus.MustRegister(elapsed)
// Remove Go collector
prometheus.Unregister(collectors.NewGoCollector())
```

Comment: thanks @dganesh2002! the only a small correction is - prometheus.NewGoCollector() is deprecated now.. 
collectors.NewGoCollector() should be used instead

Comment: For this approach, you may also want to unregister `collectors.NewProcessCollector(collectors.ProcessCollectorOpts{})` which gets registered in the `init` block of [registry.go](https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/blob/main/prometheus/registry.go#L60), at least for recent prometheus client versions.

Answer (score 4):

This solution worked from me. Idea is to create a custom registry and register our metrics. Making sure we pass `False` in handler options for open metrics will disable those default metrics

```golang
var httpDuration = prometheus.NewHistogramVec(prometheus.HistogramOpts{
        Name: "golang_api_http_duration_seconds",
        Help: "Duration of HTTP requests.",
    }, []string{"path", "host"})

promReg := prometheus.NewRegistry()
promReg.MustRegister(httpDuration)

handler := promhttp.HandlerFor(
        promReg,
        promhttp.HandlerOpts{
            EnableOpenMetrics: false,
        })


http.Handle("/metrics", handler)
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":12345", nil))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `--web.disable-exporter-metrics` now.

https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/pull/1148

Comment: Have you tried using the above flag on the latest stable version?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really helpful as an answer to say "you'd have to go and do it yourself" but it seems like the only option for now.

Since Prometheus is open source and if you really need to do that; I believe you'd have to fork [this one](https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/search?q=go_gc_duration_seconds&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) go_collector.go line #28 and the related sections, or better yet modify it to make all those metrics optional and make a PR so other people may also benefit from that in the future.